# I'm playing a video game where I got an item with 1/150 odds from 3 crates. The 3rd crate gave me 2 of the item. What are the odds of this happening?

Tags: probability

The problem is noteworthy because the game is supposed to stop giving you this item after you have 3 of them, so I might be one of the only people in game with 4 of these.

Relevant details: The item has 1/150 odds of dropping. Each crate has 2 item rolls.

There could be any number of crates in between that don't have the item, I believe this number is irrelevant here since I'm looking for the odds of this happening at all, not of it happening within a certain number of chests.

This is what I have so far but it's been about 5 years since I took probability in college, please let me know if I've somehow framed the problem incorrectly:

P (first 2 chests only have 1) * P (3rd chest has 2)

=[(1/150)(149/150)*(1/150)(149/150)] * [(1/150)(1/150)]

=22201/11390625000000

This is irreducible but I believe it's rather close to 1 in 525,000

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. But your calculation for the first two chests indicates that you want the *first* roll to be the rare item, and the *second* roll to be something else.

However, you want the probability of getting one copy of the rare item from a chest, not that the first roll is the one that gives it. Because this rare itme could come from either the first or the second roll, the probability for each of the two first chests doubles, to $2\cdot \frac1{150}\cdot\frac{149}{150}$. So the final probability is four times larger than your answer.